# How to prove that: $x_{1}x_{3}\ldots x_{2k-1}<k.$

Tags: inequality

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we define: $$A_{n}=\{x \in \mathbb{R} | [x]+[x^2]+\ldots+[x^n]=n\}.$$ Prove that for every natural numbers $k \geq 3$ and every $x_{n} \in A_{n}$ we have >$$x_{1}x_{3}\ldots x_{2k-1}<k.$$

$[a]$-integer part

Thanks :)

Comment: $[a]$-integer part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove by induction. Show that $x_{2k+1} < \frac {k+1}{k}$.

Hint: $ ( 1 + \frac {1}{k} )^m > 1 + \frac {m}{k} $.

---

Edit: This assumes that $x$ is restricted to non-negative values. But this is true because we are only looking at the odd case, in which case the integer sum of a negative value is at most 0.